# Часть речи и синтаксическая роль в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли задать к выделенному местоимению вопрос "в какой степени" и заменить его на наречие "очень"? Если да, то здесь наблюдается процесс перехода местоимения в наречие?

Она *такая* красивая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, в наречие это местоимение не переходит, так и остаётся указательным местоимением, отдельные учёные относят его к определительным местоимениям.

Местоимение "такой" указывает на высокую степень качества, если сочетается с прилагательным. Такой красивый мальчик не должен плакать.

*Она (какая?) такая красивая.* красивая - составное именное сказуемое, такая - определение, выраженное местоимением.

Переходом в наречие можно назвать по-моему, по-твоему, по-своему, по-вашему

Comment: Можно вопрос? А если бы предложение выглядело так: она казалась такой красивой, то местоимение "такой" входило бы в именную часть составного именного сказуемого? Если нет, тогда от какого слова задавать к нему вопрос, чтобы определить синтаксическую функцию, ведь оно грамматически уже не связано с именем существительным?

Comment: Она казалась  красивой (насколько красивой? как ? в какой степени красивой? какой красивой?) такой. Всё нормально, просто местоимение приобретает значение не указания на предмет, подобный тому, о котором говорили ранее (в такую ночь мне жаль людей), а указания на большую или меньшую степень качества (он такой несчастный, она такая красивая). Она очень красивая. Очень - обстоятельство. Она такая красивая.Такая - определение с оттенком обстоятельства.  Здесь определение почти сливается со сказуемым, но не становится им.

Comment: Но слово такая может быть и сказуемым: Просто она такой человек. ( = она такая) Такой человек - сказуемое, потому что без него выражение потеряло бы смысл: главное - не что она человек, а то, что она ТАКОЙ человек. А в том примере сказуемое и без слова такая самодостаточное.

Comment: Значит, в примере "она казалась такой красивой" "такой" будет обстоятельством меры и степени?

Comment: Нет, согласованным  определением со значением обстоятельства, у местоимения здесь двойная синтаксическая роль

Comment: А подчёркивать его и как определение, и как обстоятельство?

Comment: Да, сначала волнистой, потом точка-тире.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам за объяснение!